# Jquery random animation shouldn't happen if sitting underneath another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Firstly sorry for the complicity of my question!

I have a random animation that makes all the images displaying with different opacity. Some of them are sitting underneath an h1 tag.   So all the images underneath the h1 tag shouldn't animate.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/G25fT/

Currently I got tonly the random function working:

```
(function fadeInDiv() {
    var divs = $('li');
    var elem = divs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length));
    if (!elem.is(':visible')) {
        elem.prev().remove();
        elem.animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), fadeInDiv);
    } else {

        elem.animate({
            opacity: (Math.random() * 1)
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), function () {
            window.setTimeout(fadeInDiv);
        });
    }

})();
```

Comment: Your question says _So all the images underneath the h1 tag should animate_ and in fiddle it says _underneath here the animation shouldn't happen!_!

Comment: Sorry dude! underneath h1 the animation shouldn't happen!!

Comment: it's still unclear on the ***underneath***, do you mean all the images ***behind*** the `h1` should not be animated or all the images ***below*** the `h1` should not be animated?

Comment: @King King under/behind the h1! so if the h1 is on top of them:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `filter` to reduce the selectable items, based on the relative vertical positions to the h1 (the `.display` div has zero height). I check to see whether the items overlap the title at all and exclude them:

### e.g.

```
var divs = $('li').filter(function () {
        var $e = $(this);
        var top = $e.position().top;
        var bottom = top + $e.height();
        return top > h1bottom || bottom < h1top;
    });
```

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/G25fT/5/

```
(function fadeInDiv() {
    // exclude any divs 
    var $heading = $('.heading h1');
    var h1top = $heading.position().top;
    var h1bottom = h1top + $heading.height();
    //console.log("top="+ h1top + " bottom = " + h1bottom);
    var divs = $('li').filter(function () {
        var $e = $(this);
        var top = $e.position().top;
        var bottom = top + $e.height();
        return top > h1bottom || bottom < h1top;
    });
    //console.log("Len=" + divs.length);
    var elem = divs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length));
    if (!elem.is(':visible')) {
        elem.prev().remove();
        elem.animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), fadeInDiv);
    } else {

        elem.animate({
            opacity: (Math.random() * 1)
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), function () {
            window.setTimeout(fadeInDiv);
        });
    }

})();
```

### Update:

If you want to remove the styling on resize (when items move out from under the heading)

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/G25fT/11/

```
// Get the divs that should change
function displayThese() {
    var $heading = $('.heading h1');
    var h1top = $heading.position().top;
    var h1bottom = h1top + $heading.height();
    //console.log("top="+ h1top + " bottom = " + h1bottom);
    var divs = $('li').filter(function () {
        var $e = $(this);
        var top = $e.position().top;
        var bottom = top + $e.height();
        return top > h1bottom || bottom < h1top;
    });
    return divs;
}

(function fadeInDiv() {
    // exclude any divs 
    var divs = displayThese();
    //console.log("Len=" + divs.length);
    var elem = divs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length));
    if (!elem.is(':visible')) {
        elem.prev().remove();
        elem.animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), fadeInDiv);
    } else {

        elem.animate({
            opacity: (Math.random() * 1)
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), function () {
            window.setTimeout(fadeInDiv);
        });
    }

})();

$(window).resize(function () {
    // Get items that do not change    
    var divs = $('li').not(displayThese());
    divs.css({
        opacity: .3
    });
});
```

Comment: No problem. (I'd settle for the green tick - when you can) :>

Comment: mate what happen if the h1 is lower that the current position?

Comment: It should still work as I check for non-overlap (completely above or below the h1). If you can change the fiddle styling to suit your header, I can ensure it works in all cases (it should).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55578/discussion-between-user3699998-and-trueblueaussie).

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to detect if the image is under the title would be something like:

```
var titleTop = $('.heading').position().top;
var divs = $('li');
var elem = divs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length));
var elemTop = elem.position().top;
var elemHeight = elem.height();


if (titleTop < elemTop || titleTop > elemTop + elemHeight) {
    //it's not overlapping, do the animation
} else {
    //it's overlapping
}
```

Basically it's saying "if the title's position is less than the position of the current element or if the title's position is more than the the current element position + the current element's height, do the animation, otherwise don't"

I did it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/G25fT/2/
You'll need to rework your loop though, but it should get you going

If your page has a scroll and you see it stops working, try using `offset()` instead of `postition()`

Comment: @Jonas Grumann thanks dude! really nice. Rework my loop? any idea how?

Comment: Right now you recall the function inside the if/else. I think you should be calling it after the if/else. Something like http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/G25fT/3/ (it's still not perfect)

Comment: nice one, not sure what should be the perfect one for you:-)

Comment: @JonasGrumann what do you mean with perfect? Not sure the random animation?

Comment: we should filter the `li`s first. doing so will make the animation perfect.

Comment: @King King : Funny enough that's exactly the approach I took. See new answer.

Comment: I'd say we have a winrar ;) nice one @TrueBlueAussie

Comment: Just took me a while to realise it was the zero height div causing all my problems :)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: you could figure out the horizontal and vertical offset of the heading, then compare it all the time with the offsets of the images

Comment: Nice *comment*... now if only you supplied the code :)

Comment: Yeah I wish I could! not sure how long is going to take me!

Comment: Approximately 30 minutes (if you ran into the same problem I did) :)

Answer (score 0):

With the current html you'll need to determine how many li are in the first row (we'll call it numFirstRow) and change you div selector to this:

```
var divs = $('li:nth-child(n+numFirstRow)');
```

implemented it here: http://jsfiddle.net/G25fT/7/

Comment: The number of columns changes based on the window size.

Comment: @Dave Briand would u be able to put it together on a fiddle?

Comment: That fiddle does nothing either :(

Comment: Sorry about that - copied the wrong one. Works now.

Comment: Reload the page and it does - you could tie this to a window.resize() to recalc the ul width.

Comment: Never mind. The SO clarified requirements that it support the `h1` banner anywhere on their page. This approach will unfortunately not support that :(